# GNU Assembler - Program breaks when I change the string

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm working on some simple GNU Code just trying to print two strings using a format string and 1 printf. The thing is when I change string1 from "Equal Created Were Women All\0" to "I do not like using Assembly\0" the program breaks after printing the two strings and says a.exe is not working.

```
    # pgm that calls a user function

    # set up globals
    .text
    .globl _main
    _string:            .ascii "All women were created equal\0"
    _string1:           .ascii "Equal Created Were Women All\0"
    _format:            .ascii "%s\n%s\0"

    #the main() function - simply call user fn

    #push parameters, call function, clear parameters, return
    _main: 
            pushl $_string1
            pushl $_string
            call _printStr
            addl $4, %esp
            ret

    #function to print a string passed to it on the stack
    _printStr:
            push %ebp       #save old frame pointer
            movl %esp, %ebp   #set frame pointer
            pushl 8(%ebp)
            pushl 12(%ebp)
            pushl $_format
            call _printf
            addl $, %esp
            leave
            ret
```

Above is the working code

```
    # pgm that calls a user function

    # set up globals
    .text
    .globl _main
    _string:            .ascii "All women were created equal\0"
    _string1:           .ascii "I do not like using Assembly\0"
    _format:            .ascii "%s\n%s\0"

    #the main() function - simply call user fn

    #push parameters, call function, clear parameters, return
    _main: 
            pushl $_string1
            pushl $_string
            call _printStr
            addl $4, %esp
            ret

    #function to print a string passed to it on the stack
    _printStr:
            push %ebp       #save old frame pointer
            movl %esp, %ebp   #set frame pointer
            pushl 8(%ebp)
            pushl 12(%ebp)
            pushl $_format
            call _printf
            addl $, %esp
            leave
            ret
```

This is the broke code. I assume that it is not breaking just because of the string but I honestly I have no idea where to go from here. I thought I might not be clearing the whole stack but that didn't seem to be it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are pushing 2 arguments, so you should remove 2 arguments. Also `addl $, %esp` is nonsense and shouldn't even compile.

Comment: my bad it should be, addl $4, %esp

Comment: It most certainly shouldn't :)  You are pushing 3 arguments there, so you need to remove 3 as well. At that point you got lucky, because `leave` takes care of that for you even if you mess up the stack pointer.